# GDAL Open error in C#

Tags: gdal, c#, osgeo

I want to open a csv raster data file with GDAL in C#

```
Dataset csvFile = Gdal.Open(fileLocation, Access.GA_ReadOnly);
```

Produce an error saying that

```
At line 4, X is 412267, where as 412555 was expected
```

I tried to change the `X` manually but instead it is saying

```
At line 4, X is 412555, where as 412555 was expected
```

What confused me more is when I tried to open this csv file with `C++` or `python` it works fine.

Here the `python` code I used

```
dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
```

Anyone here facing the similar problem with me?